# I can not change language on xwiki

Tags: xwiki

Dose anyone know how to change language on xwiki?

I followed this link below, but, nothing change at all.

http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/I18N

The step is following.

1. Go to XWikiPreferences.
2. Click content.
3. Click localization.
4. Change SUPPORTED LANGUAGES and default language.

I am Japanese so I choose Japanese, namely 日本語.

5. Set timezone
6. Click on save button.

Environment: Centos 6
             java 1.8.0
             xwiki 10.1

Do I have to take another action when I want to change language?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: It worked, but unfortunately XWiki's User Interface is not yet translated into Japanese. Check by editing a page and looking at the editor's labels.

Longer answer:
As you can see from the link you mentioned (and the updated list http://l10n.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/L10N/ - see the "Supported Languages" panel, on the right), XWiki does not list Japanese as supported language. This just means that there are no available translations for that language, so the User Interface will show the text labels in the English default.

This does not stop you from setting your wiki, as you did, to use the Japanese language. One way to check that the setting has taken effect is to edit a page and see the WYSIWYG editor's UI showing labels (like when hovering with the mouse over its buttons) in Japanese. This is a bit of a special case, since that editor provides its own translations and it just happens that it includes Japanese. (for information, that component is a 3rd party project, integrated into XWiki, so it manages its own translations that get distributed and integrated with the editor)

Additionally, if you set your wiki to be multilingual, it makes sense to use even languages where the UI is not translated yet because you will be able to edit various translations for the same page, should your usecase need that feature.

If you want to do something about it, you are welcomed to check out the translations wiki http://l10n.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/L10N/ and start translating XWiki's UI for the Japanese language. The next release will include your translations and a lot of people, including yourself, will be grateful for it :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. When I have a time for it, I will translate xwiki.

Comment: Well...it seems that the web site is very slow.

Comment: I added JIRA ticket for the Japanese translation. So, please check it out.